# How to bake mesh normals with the original texture normal

Tags: normals, baking

Say, I have a textured high-poly object (Obj_A). I applied a normal map on it using an image (Img_NRM). Now, I want to bake the normal map to a low-poly object. When I do this, I only get the normal map from the mesh structure of Obj_A.

How do I get the normal map from the mesh structure of Obj_A plus the original texture map Img_NRM?